# Почему скомпилированная в exe не находит файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Указываю кусок кода, который удаляет файл и создает на его месте файл с таким же именем, без компиляции все работает хорошо

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), f'{file_name}.xlsx')
os.remove(path)
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f'{file_name}.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(f'J1', 'Компания')
worksheet.write(f'K1', 'Адрес')
worksheet.write(f'L1', 'Электронка')
for i,(name) in enumerate(names,start = 2):
    worksheet.write(f'J{i}', name)
for i,(adress) in enumerate(adresses,start = 2):
    worksheet.write(f'K{i}', adress)
for i,(email) in enumerate(emails,start = 2):
    worksheet.write(f'L{i}', email)
workbook.close()
print('Парсинг завершен!!!')
```

Но после перевода в exe выдает следующую ошибку

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'C:\\Users\\Bubunduc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI52122\\Сбор электронок - ШАБЛОН 2.xlsx'
[9644] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), f'{file_name}.xlsx')
os.remove(path)
```

заменил на простой

```
os.remove(f'./{имя файла}.xlsx')
```

И всё заработало

Comment: Если включить шаблон в сам exe файл, то первый вариант заработает. При запуске такого exe файла, полученного через pyinstaller, все его содержимое распаковывается во временную папку, если в него же будет вшит и xlsx шаблон, то все будет работать.